# Postioning JFreeChart Image with Itext 5

Tags: java, image, itext, jfreechart

I have created a JFreeChart image and am having trouble positioning it. The lower left corner of the image is placed on the lower left corner of the page.

```
Rectangle page=writer.getPageSize();
// swap X and Y for Landscape dimensions
float sizeX=page.getHeight();
float sizeY=page.getWidth();
float scale=.7f;
float marginY=10.f;
float marginX=50.f;
PdfContentByte cb=writer.getDirectContent();
PdfTemplate tp=cb.createTemplate(sizeX*scale+1,sizeY*scale+1);
PdfGraphics2D g2d=new PdfGraphics2D(tp,sizeX*scale+1,sizeY*scale+1);
tp.setWidth(sizeX*scale+1);
tp.setHeight(sizeY*scale+1);
Chart.getInstance().getChart().draw(g2d, new java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Float(0,0,sizeX*scale,sizeY*scale));
g2d.dispose();
Image image=Image.getInstance(tp);
image.setAbsolutePosition(marginX, sizeY-350.f);
document.add(image);
```

I would like the upper left corner of the image to be placed at the current cursor position. What am I doing wrong? TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create the `PdfGraphics2D` for the direct page content `cb`, not the template `tp`:

```
PdfGraphics2D g2d=new PdfGraphics2D(cb,sizeX*scale+1,sizeY*scale+1);
```

Thus, the chart is directly drawn into `cb` and your handling of `tp` does not matter at all!

You should, therefore, initialize `PdfGraphics2D` with the template `tp`:

```
PdfGraphics2D g2d=new PdfGraphics2D(tp,sizeX*scale+1,sizeY*scale+1);
```

Furthermore you add `tp` to the page twice, first to its direct content

```
cb.add(tp);
```

and then wrapped in an `Image` instance to its `Document document`.

```
Image image=Image.getInstance(tp);
image.setAbsolutePosition(marginX, sizeY-marginY);
document.add(image);
```

Obviously you should add it but once.

Comment: Thanks. That was it. The double add was a result of trying different things to make it move. I changed the OP to show the corrected code.